# Teapot Riddle no.22 (fan made)

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

**Teapot Riddle no.22 (fan made).** 
 *Alien*.

> > **Rules:**
>
> *I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**.
>
> Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...).
>
> You try to figure out the word with my Hints.*

- **First Hint:**

  > My first teapot grows, and my second will rest. 
  >  You might see your nose or some weird clouds at best.
- **Second Hint:**

  > My first teapot shows itself in a commandment. 
  >  My second has chosen the fallen, much absent.
- **Third Hint:**

  > My first teapot cannot keep promises much; 
  >  It began with a plan of betrayal and such.
- **Final Hint (to make it easy):**

  > My second is down and through it you see dreams. 
  >  It can be a noun or verb under the seams.

Good luck and have fun!
[Last teapot riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72677/teapot-riddle-no-21?noredirect=1&lq=1). Big thanks to @[Jannis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52327/jannis) for making them!

Also, the title of [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/63576/an-alien-message) was my inspiration for *this* puzzle's title.

Comment: An upvote already? Thank you, @upvoter :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it is the word

> lie

My first teapot grows, and my second will rest. You might see your nose or some weird clouds at best.

> Lying causes Pinocchio's nose to grow; you lie down to rest, and if you're outdoors you'll see clouds in the sky.

My first teapot shows itself in a commandment. My second has chosen the fallen, much absent.

> Thou shalt not lie; if you fall down, you'll end up lying down.

My first teapot cannot keep promises much; It began with a plan of betrayal and such.

> If you lie, you would not keep your word. Lies are also often thought out in advance.

My second is down and through it you see dreams. 
It can be a noun or verb under the seams.

> When you lie down, you sleep and see dreams. Sleep can be either a noun or a verb, and you'd sleep under a blanket made of seams!

Comment: I think that is the answer :) +1

Comment: Yes, @Duck is right; this is the correct answer. Well done! I will give you a hint on the part you are unsure of: (ROT13) Odnokd vgn gzud "ezkkdm" zqd vgdqd cnhmf vgzs? Zmc mn, ynlahdr zqdm's hmbktcdc :P

Comment: @user477343: that's not rot13. For future people who want to decode: add 1 to the letter or apply rot1 or decode rot25.

Comment: edited! although there are many positions you can end up falling in...

Comment: @ev3commander holy crap it *is* Rot1. I am very sorry. I do not know why I was on Rot1. I could have sworn I was on Rot13. In fact, I thought you were being ridiculous when I first read your comment, so I'm sorry for that, too.

Comment: @user477343, it's ok, i just wanted to help people.

Comment: That 'falling" part is still incorrect. I will give you one more hint, and this time it *is* in Rot13: "Gur fbyqvref unir snyyra!" (And also, the title is related. In fact, (ROT13) Gur nafjre pna or sbhaq va gur gvgyr.) :D

Comment: Okay, it's been $3$ days. Nevermind that part. Congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$